# gitlab-ci manually start multiple jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am on a self-hosted Gitlab CE (current version) and I am trying to achieve the following CI/CD pipeline with four phases, each having exactly one job:

- compile
- asssemble
- package
- deploy

On a commit on a feature branch, gitlab-ci should run the `compile` job to compile the code and perform the tests, ensuring the code more or less works. This runs as expected.

For a merge request, the gitlab-ci should also perform compile (although it is already triggered by the commit), and should additionally offer a manual step which deploys 'review app' to allow my QA team to test before merging the feature branch back to the target branch.

However, deployment requires multiple jobs: `assemble` (create WAR), `package` (create/push image) and `deploy` (helm stack to OKD).

I have successfully defined rules to make the final `deploy` step manual (always performing `assemble` and `package`), or I can make all steps manual, but then QA needs to click them in the correct order.

What I would like to do is make the `assemble` step manual and when it is performed, it must then then trigger the `package` and `deploy` in the correct order.

I basically understand the [CI variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) and [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html) but I cannot seem to grok how to model this simple task.

The obfuscated `gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
      image: gradle:7.5.1-jdk17-alpine

      default:
        cache: &global_cache
          key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
          policy: pull-push
          paths:
            # retain gradle cache
            - .gradle/
            # retain artifact cache
            - .m2/
            # retain all artifacts from subprojects to optimize repeat builds
            - "**/build/"

      stages:
        - compile 
        - build
        - package
        - deploy
        
      # always build sub projects, other jobs only on MR
      compile:
        stage: compile
        script:
          - echo "Compiling classes for ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} at ${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} ..."
          - gradle  --build-cache -Prevision=${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} -Pdist=true --init-script init.gradle buildSubprojects

      # build ear for deployment in docker only on merge request
      build-ear:
        stage: build
        script:
          - echo "Building parent EAR for ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} at ${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} ..."
          - gradle --build-cache -Prevision=${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} -Pdist=true --init-script init.gradle buildParentEar
        variables:
          GIT_STRATEGY: fetch

        artifacts:
          # archiving EAR to allow specific testing outside k8s if required
          expire_in: 3 day 
          expose_as: 'Download EAR'
          paths: ['parent/build/libs/my.ear']
        rules:
          - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" 

      # build and push new docker image on MR
      build-docker-image:
        stage: package
        image: docker
        services:
          - docker:dind
        needs:
          - build-ear
        # already build in previous step, result is in cache
        variables:
          GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
        script: 
          #- build image then remove local copy
          - docker build -t "${IMAGE_NAME}" -f kubernetes/image/Dockerfile .
          - docker push "${IMAGE_NAME}"
          - docker image rm -f "${IMAGE_NAME}"
        rules:
          - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
        cache:
          # inherit all global cache settings
          <<: *global_cache
          # override the policy - only pull
          policy: pull

      deploy as review app:
        image: dtzar/helm-kubectl:latest
        stage: deploy
        when: manual
        variables:
          GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
        needs:
        - build-docker-image
        script:
          - echo "Deploying changes from branch ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} to ${HELM_APP_NAME}"
          - DISTDIR="${distDir:-dist}" && helm --kube-context  $CTX upgrade ${HELM_APP_NAME} ./kubernetes/helm --install --values=./kubernetes/helm/values.yaml --set-string "image.name=${IMAGE_NAME},hostname=${K8S_APP_URL},distDir=$DISTIDR" -n helm-charts 
        environment: 
          name: $REVIEW_APP_NAME
          url: $REVIEW_APP_URL
          on_stop: stop_review_environment
          auto_stop_in: 3 days
        rules:
          - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
        # no cache required, we are just deploying with helm
        cache: []

      stop_review_environment:
        image: dtzar/helm-kubectl:latest
        stage: deploy
        when: manual
        variables:
          GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
        script:
          - helm --kube-context  $CTX uninstall $HELM_APP_NAME -n staging-helm-charts || true 
        environment: 
          name: $REVIEW_APP_NAME
          url: $REVIEW_APP_URL
          action: stop
        rules:
          - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
        # no cache required, we are just undeploying with helm
        cache: []
```

Answer (score 0):

OK embarassing as it is, I asked OpenAI for this and it basically solved it for me. I had to make a couple small changes, but essentially it is this:

```yaml
stages:
  - compile
  - assemble
  - package
  - deploy

compile_job:
  stage: compile
  script:
    - echo "Compiling code..."
    # Add your compilation commands here

assemble_job:
  stage: assemble
  script:
    - echo "Assembling code..."
    # Add your assembly commands here
  when: manual

package_job:
  stage: package
  script:
    - echo "Packaging code..."
    # Add your packaging commands here
  needs:
    - assemble_job
  when: on_success

deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploying code..."
    # Add your deployment commands here
  needs:
    - package_job
  when: on_success
```